# Quiero que se muestre la info de post creado

Tags: laravel, formularios, laravel-8, laravelcollective

les presento mi inconveniente.

Estoy creando un Blog en Laravel 8, estoy utilizando Laravel/collective para los formularios, por lo que en la vista editar trato d e mostrar los datos con From::Model y paso mi variable $post, pero resulta que me está retornando vacio.
Este es mi controlador de post:

```
 public function edit(Post $post)
{
    // return($post); //Me retorna un array vacio ¿?
    $categories = Category::pluck('name','id');
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return view('admin.posts.edit', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));
}
```

Esta es mi vista edit

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    {!! Form::model($post, []) !!}
   

    {!! Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) !!}

    @include('admin.posts.partials.form')

    {!! Form::submit('Editar Post', ['class' => 'btn btn-success float-right ']) !!}


    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Este es mi Modelos con sus relaciones

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
// relacion uno a muchos inversa

public function user()
{
    # code...
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function category()
{
    # code...
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
// relacion muchos a muchos 

public function tags(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}

//relacion uno a uno polimorfica 

public function image(){

  return  $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
}
```

}

Estas son las rutas

```
Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class)->names('admin.categories');
Route::resource('tags', TagController::class)->names('admin.tags');
Route::resource('postsa', PostaController::class)->names('admin.posts');
```

Este es el formulario

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Nombre') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el nombre del post']) !!}

    @error('name')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
    @enderror
                
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    {!! Form::label('slug', 'Slug') !!}
    {!! Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el slug del post',  'readonly']) !!}

    @error('slug')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
    @enderror

</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Categoría') !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    @error('category_id')
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
    @enderror
   
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <p class="font-weight-bold">Estado</p>
    <label class="mr-2"> 
        {!! Form::radio('status', 1, true) !!}
        Borrador
    </label>
    <label class="mr-2"> 
        {!! Form::radio('status', 2) !!}
        Publicado
    </label>
   
    @error('status')
    <hr>
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
    @enderror

</div>
<div class="col-md-12 my-3">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <h3>Etiquetas</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group ">                  
                @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                <label class="mx-2">
                    {!! Form::checkbox('tags[]', $tag->id, null) !!}
                    {{$tag->name}}
                </label>
                    
                @endforeach
                
                @error('tags')
                <hr>
                    <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
               
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12 my-4">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <h3>Imagen del Post</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row mb-3 ">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img id="picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/01/28/03/13/person-5956897_960_720.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('file', 'Imagen del Post') !!}
                        {!! Form::file('file', ['class' => 'form-control-file', 'accept' => 'image/*']) !!}
                        @error('file')
                            <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>    
                             
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer bg-warning">
        <small class="text-white">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle x3 text-white"></i>
             Para una mejor visualización de la imagen que vas a 
             poner en el post, debe tener medidas 16:9.
            </small>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 my-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <h4>Extracto del post</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group ">
                {!! Form::label('extract', 'Extracto') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('extract', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            
                @error('extract')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

</div>
<div class="div-col-md-12 my-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <h4>Cuerpo del post</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('body', 'Cuerpo') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                @error('body')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En fin me he dado cuenta que no me muestra nada por que me está retornando un array vacion pero no se por que no está funcionando, necesito de su ayuda.

Comment: Cómo es la ruta que apunta a ese método edit del controlador?

Comment: Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class)->names('admin.categories');
Route::resource('tags', TagController::class)->names('admin.tags');
Route::resource('postsa', PostaController::class)->names('admin.posts');

Comment: `Route::resource('postsa', PostaController::class)->names('admin.posts');`

Comment: Prueba si funciona poniendo `$postsa` en lugar de `$post` a la variable que inyectas en la función edit: `public function edit(Post $postsa) {...`

Comment: No ya lo puesto y no me devuelve un array vacio.

Comment: De todas formas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: ¿Cual es el nombre del parámetro de esa ruta si haces un `php artisan route:list`? Ten en cuenta lo que dice en la [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) de laravel > Dado que la variable `$user` está insinuada como el modelo App\User y el nombre de la variable coincide con el segmento de URI de `{user}`, Laravel inyectará automáticamente la instancia del modelo que tiene una ID que coincide con el valor correspondiente del URI de solicitud.